# No Material Widget Found and Bottom Overflowed By Huge number of Pixels

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. First of all, I've tried using `Scaffold` and also changing the `mainAxisSize` after looking at some answers here but both don't solve the issue. Setting the height of the container doesn't work as well. Here's where I use the `midContent`: [Mainpage that includes midContent](https://pastebin.com/kDfBLUew) .
And here's my code for `midContent`:

```
return Container(
        height: 200,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.ellipsis,
                          color: Colors.white, size: 30),
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2),
                          child: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.ellipsis,
                              color: Colors.white, size: 30))
                    ]),
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                        icon: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.eyeSlash,
                            size: 12, color: Color(0xF2FAA381)),
                        tooltip: 'Tap to show balance',
                        onPressed: () {}),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                      child: Text(
                        'Show Balance',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Lato',
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Color(0xF2FAA381),
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
```

Comment: Can you add an image to better understand your issue?

Comment: How's the title related to the question?

Comment: @SamuelOlufemi @intraector [This](https://imgur.com/a/2AV5Knh) is what I would like it to be but this is the [error](https://imgur.com/a/1pfysTf) I face when I use `IconButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the main widget where the **topBar** widget is called has this tree :

```
MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
      body: ...
   )
);
```

It can be more simple and easy to help you, if you provide a full description of the code where the topBar is called.

Comment: Here's where [topBar](https://pastebin.com/350vfskp) is called.

Comment: Just added my widget to `Scaffold` and the problem is now solved. Thank you so much!